# This is a flood sensor. Moisture sensor and servo working together but it shows different errors

Tags: sensors, servo

Sometimes the servo moves unnecessarily without moisture sensor giving out any readings.

Another problem is that the servo moves very slowly. Is there a way to counter this problem?

```cpp
const int VAL_PROBE = 0; // Analog pin 0
const int MOISTURE_LEVEL = 250; // the value after the LED goes ON
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myservo;

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(9);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void Servo(int state) {
  digitalWrite(13, state);
}

void loop() {
  int moisture = analogRead(VAL_PROBE);

  Serial.println(moisture);

  if(moisture > MOISTURE_LEVEL) {
    myservo.write(90);
  } else {
    myservo.write(0);
  }
  delay(1);
}
```

Comment: Try giving external power supply to Servo( not from Arduino )

Comment: Your sketch is missing `pinMode` for the pins your are using.

Comment: @LookAlterno please elaborate

Comment: The only pin that could possibly need a pinMode is in a function that is never called.

Comment: What do you mean by that

Comment: One complete year and no answer??